# rule defined in a Makefile template does not work

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use a template with foreach to create multiple rules construction. Following is my entire example code.

```makefile
variable.mk:
    echo 'variable.mk'
    echo 'test variable.mk' > $@


FILES:=cpf dma
define generate_template
$(warning input is $(1) end)
$(1): variable.mk
    echo [CC] $(1)
    echo 'test $(1)' > $(1)
endef

$(foreach module,$(FILES),$(eval $(call generate_template,$(module))))

run.sh:cpf dma
    echo [CC] run.sh
    echo 'TEST run.sh' >$@
```

But when I run `make run.sh` on the command line, it shows below error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `cpf', needed by `run.sh'.  Stop.
```

The rule for `cpf` target is expected to be created by the template `generate_template` in line 14, but it does not work as expect. 
Could someone help me out of this issue? I searched around the google, but I still could not figure it out.

Comment: run.sh needs cpf target to be built but you don't say to make program, how to achieve it(cpf target). You need to create rule for cpf target

Comment: That's is my point. The rule for  cpf target should be  created by the template `generate_template` from line 7 to line 14. But the template does not work as expect.

Comment: It works for me, GNU Make 4.2.1

Comment: @Mike Kinghan,   Well, when I use Make 4.2.1, it still failed but with another error message: ```make: *** No rule to make target 'variable.mk
', needed by 'cpf'.  Stop.
```     I could not figure out why there is a whitespace/newline after variable.mk.

Comment: There must be some extra character after `variable.mk` in the definition of `generate_template` in your makefile, which shows up as a space but is not a standard space character.  Try deleting that.

Comment: somehow, it works with 4.2.1 now. Could not figure out why it failed previously. Thanks, Mike.

Comment: In case of someone else is sufferring the same pain I have, here is how I fixed my issue. 

 1. First of all, make sure your GNU Make version is not out of date. I tried with GNU Make 4.2.1 as suggested by Mike Kinghan. 
 2. If the above still does not work, try Stefan Becker's suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typical mistake trying to use `$(eval ...)` on generated rules: you generator is not generating the final line end and therefore `make` doesn't parse the generated rules as you think it should be parsing them.

Solution: ***Always*** end multi-line macros that define rule(s) with an empty line. That makes sure that the rules are `$(eval)`'d correctly.

```makefile
variable.mk:
    echo $@
    echo 'test $@' > $@

FILES := cpf dma

# the empty line at the end of the macro is on purpose 
define generate_template
$(warning input is $(1) end)
$(1): variable.mk
    echo [CC] $$@
    echo 'test $$@' > $$@

endef

$(foreach module,$(FILES),$(eval $(call generate_template,$(module))))

run.sh: cpf dma
    echo [CC] $@
    echo 'TEST $@' >$@
```

Test run:

```
$ make run.sh
Makefile:14: input is cpf end
Makefile:14: input is dma end
echo variable.mk
variable.mk
echo 'test variable.mk' > variable.mk
echo [CC] cpf
[CC] cpf
echo 'test cpf' > cpf
echo [CC] dma
[CC] dma
echo 'test dma' > dma
echo [CC] run.sh
[CC] run.sh
echo 'TEST run.sh' >run.sh

$ cat variable.mk cpf dma run.sh 
test variable.mk
test cpf
test dma
TEST run.sh
```

---

I would also suggest to rewrite your macro to only perform the evaluation once, i.e.

```makefile
$(eval $(foreach module,$(FILES),$(call generate_template,$(module))))
```

---

**TIP:** in case of `$(eval ...)` not working as expected I always change it to `$(info eval ...)` to see exactly what is being evaluated. That usually makes it easy to pin-point mistakes and typos in code generation macros.

Comment: There's no need to leave a blank line at the end of a `define` macro when defining rules like this: make can parse makefiles that don't have trailing newlines.  However your suggestion to replace `eval` with `info` to see what make sees is a good one.

Comment: @MadScientist I have encountered this `$(eval)` problem so many times and almost always the empty trailing line at the end of the macro fixed it that I now always add it automatically. It is the only change I made to OPs original makefile to make it work (well I had to restore the TABs, because they don't survive copy & paste).

Comment: I followed your code but it still failed when I use GNU Make 3.79.1. Then I tried using GNU Make 4.2.1,  it works! So it seems to be caused by the GNU Make version, not the missing empty line at the end of multi-lines macros.

Comment: Why are you still trying to use GNU make 3.79.1? As far as I recall it had so many bugs and essential features were missing, that we added a version check in the makefile templates to fail immediately if a SW developer tried to run the build with anything older than 3.80. That was over 10 years ago...

Comment: I ran the original without the newline and it worked.  FWIW, I never add newlines to the end of my defines and it always works.  The only time you need to do it is when you really need a newline at the end if the define and that's never the case for a define that is going to be used with eval, because eval gives you a whole new parse context (like reading a new file), and make does not require parse contexts to end with a newline (like a makefile doesn't have to end with a newline).  There are other ways to use define macros that do require a newline.